# How could I change my Firebase login account to another account and login again during the Firebase hosting process?

Tags: firebase-hosting, firebase-tools

For firebase hosting, I installed gooble firebase tools with executing 'npm install -g firebase-tools' command in my firebase project. Then I wanted to execute 'firebase login' command to initialize project, but I couldn't execute because I already logged in with another Google email before. So I want to cancel 'firebase login' and login again with another account but I don't know how to do.
I thought about installing Google Firebase tools again after deleting and reinstalling npm. But I think this will have a bad effect on the package(-lock).json that others have added and make things big, so I'm going to look for another way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So I want to cancel 'firebase login' and login again with another account

If I correctly understand your question you should use the CLI `firebase logout` command followed by the `firebase login` one.

Answer (score 2):

With Firebase CLI you can have multiple accounts logged in.

Using `firebase login:add` will login another account.

Using `firebase login:list` will list logged accounts.

Using `firebase login:use` will set default account for current project directory.

[More info in Firebase CLI README](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/blob/master/README.md)

And you can use `firebase logout` to logout from Firebase.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer! Thank you @snsxn !! This is GOLD!